# How to decrypt item in SQLite database using python 3

Tags: python, sqlite, encryption

I am trying to verify that the correct password has been entered into the password input box on my site. The aim is to return true if the password entered matches the password in the SQLite table that corresponds the "usernick" entered in the username input box.

```
def check_login(db, usernick, password):
    """returns True if password matches stored"""
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE nick='%s'" % usernick)
    passcheck = cursor.fetchone()
    print(usernick)
    print(password)
    print(passcheck)
    if password == passcheck:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I used the print's to see where my code was going wrong. The correct username and passwords are being inputted into the function, but print(passcheck) is outputting:
['48181acd22b3edaebc8a447868a7df7ce629920a']

I now realise that this is because the password is decrypted. How do i decrypt the password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You encrypt the password the user has entered and check that it matches the encrypted version in the database.

However without any details of how the database certain was originally created, there is no way to help you further.

**Edit**

Remember that `fetchone()` always returns a tuple, even if you only selected a single column. Do `passcheck = cursor.fetchone()[0]`.

Comment: ah ok thanks. This is what i should have been doing. So i encrypted the password going into the function. But the password im retrieving from the database is not being matched because the password im retreiving from the database comes enclosed like so: ('48181acd22b3edaebc8a447868a7df7ce629920a',). Is there a way to remove the brackets and quotations ?

Comment: When i use passcheck = cursor.fetchone()[0] i get an error that says 'nonetype' object is not subscriptable. and my print for passcheck shows all the passwords and usernames in the database with 2 encrypted pass values per username.